# What is the advantage of using AWS Config Conformance Pack?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-config

Recently in December 2019, AWS introduced a new service feature called Conformance Pack,

> A conformance pack is a collection of AWS Config rules and remediation
>   actions in a cloudformation templete that can be easily deployed in an account and a region.

My question is if we can deploy a cloud-formation template of Config rules and remediation action with awscli command of "create-stack" then why AWS introduced Conformance Pack feature ? **What is the advantage of using conformance pack over creating a stack from awscli command?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The main advantage IMO is that Conformance Pack brings sets of best-practices:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/conformancepack-sample-templates.html

as templates of rules which can be used "as is" or edited and costumed to your needs.

Yes, you can write the rules by yourself but why not start with a baseline of best-practices?

An [additional benefit](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/11/introducing-aws-config-conformance-packs/) of Conformance Packs is when your organization has multiple AWS accounts:

> This is particularly useful if you need to quickly establish a common baseline for resource configuration policies and best practices across multiple accounts in your organization in a scalable and efficient way.